# Magento2 reload price

Tags: magento2, price, javascript, quantity

How can I call `reloadPrice` from `price-box.js` on product detail page when user change the quantity from quantity box?

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code for updating price:

```
$("div.price-box .price-final_price").trigger("updatePrice");
```

you can check it with reloadPrice as well.